# Count every onclick event in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

JS

```
<script> 
    function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'}
      });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="'. $row['link'] .'"target="_blank" onclick="myAjax()">
```

PHP

```
<?php
    require ("static/php/inc/betaconfig.inc.php");
    if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
        $conn->query("UPDATE users SET clicks = (clicks + 1) WHERE id = 13");   
    }
?>
```

Normally it should be $uid instead of 13 but I don't know how to do that too...
First of all, why this doesnt work ? 2nd $uid is `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` and then

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `link` WHERE id = '$id'";
$result4 = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
    $uid = $row['userid'];
}
```

so the best thing that instead of 13 I could use $uid

Comment: youre missing an enclosing bracket in your JS. The console would have told you...

Comment: whe also it doesnt tell me any errors

Comment: oh yeah I see... now it works, but still how to use uid in this script

Comment: `ctrl+shift+J` in Chrome or Firefox will bring up your console, which will include JS errors.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "use uid"?  What is the value you're trying to use?  What are you trying to use it for?  Where does it come from?

Comment: If you want to send an ID in the request, add it to the `data:` object: `data: {action: 'call_this', id: my_userid }`. But getting the ID from the client seems dubious. You probably should be using a session variable that gets set when the user logs in.

Comment: I already found that out but thanks... also it is a small project like a link shortener, there is an id for each link then it searches for the userid that is linked to the link and update infs like clicks and all